running a bash script from udev rule
I have read through the other similar questions, but the answer there do not work in my case.
I have a udev rule in file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-headset_switcher.rules
The rule is
ACTION=="add", RUN="/usr/local/bin/switch_headset.sh"

When I run udevadm test /sys/class/bluetooth/hci0
I see
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
DEVTYPE=host
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
TAGS=:systemd:
CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:
SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0
SYSTEMD_WANTS=bluetooth.target
SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=bluetooth.target
USEC_INITIALIZED=9792645
run: '/usr/local/bin/switch_headset.sh'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.

Which indicates that my script is running. The script contains
cat /usr/local/bin/switch_headset.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/echo switching headset >>/tmp/headset.log


The udev test does not append anything to the log file, If I run the file in a shell it works fine.
Things I have tried so far.

Changed all paths to absolute path.
Tried RUN+= and RUN=
Removed everything from my rule and incrementally built it from RUN..., Nothing worked.
I know udev rules run for a very small time. but I dont think that is the problem here.

Any hints on what I am missing out is welcome.

is this really the script you want to run? Because if you need a log entry that says that the you switched, that can be directly extracted from system logs (or by listening on the appropriate buses, in case you need to be notified).

The script is for testing the setup. My actual intent is to switch my active microphone to the bluetooth headset as an when it is active(for some reason my setup automatically switches the headphone to the headset when available, but keeps the microphone set to the laptop microphone).

Hm, my system does this on its own when I mark the headset as the primary microphone while it's active, and then later disconnect and re-connect it. So, that functionality is already there, in pulseaudio, probably

Your system may have set up a PrivateTmp. Look through systemctl cat systemd-udevd.service and for a directory in /tmp/systemd-private-*/.

systemctl cat ... did not show PrivateTemp,
systemctl show systemd-udevd.service showed PrivateTmp=no

There are a bunch of  /tmp/systemd-private* folders. these contain a tmp folder. the tmp folder is empty for all.
